# Open Navigation Drawer at startup

Tags: java, android, navigation, startup, drawer

I'm fairly new to android programming and developed an app that has a Navigation Drawer implemented. Per Google guidelines, i'd like the NavDraw to start open but am unable to do this.

This is my onCreate (I guess this is where I should implement this feature, right?)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuEntries);

    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawer,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
    )
```

(...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);`

Comment: If targeting international users, use GravityCompat.START instead.

Comment: You should probably wrap in `if (savedInstanceState == null)`, so that the drawer doesn't open on configuration/orientation change

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

or

```
drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT`);
```